# Spring Boot MongoDB: Can @GeneratedValue and @Column annotations be used?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have been learning how to use MongoDB in Spring Boot; for this purpose I am trying to build a service that allows sending posts and commenting on posts in a forum. Currently I have created a model class for forum posts:

```
@Document
@Data
public class ForumPost {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long postId;

  private Long userId;

  private String postTitle;

  private String postContent;

  @DbRef
  private List<Comment> comments;

  private Instant createTime;

  private Instant updateTime;
  
}
```

In RDBMS like PostgreSQL I would use `@GeneratedValue` to automatically generate ID value and  `@Column` to define the column definition and other settings like `updatable` for each variable. But would this be possible using Spring Data MongoDB? Are there any equivalent annotations that can be used to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Mongo will automatically generate an ID for you. It's customary to use the Mongo OID type (use `String` in Java) rather than `Long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id type can be a `String` or `ObjectId`(from Mongo drivers), annotated with an `@Id`(from Spring data commons), Spring Data MongoDB will fill this field automatically when persisting this document.

Check [my simple Spring Mongo example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/data-mongo) and [the real world like example](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample).

Generally, the `@GeneratedValue` is from JPA, only used for JPA entities. If you want to use JPA similar APIs on noSQL, check [Hibernate OGM](https://hibernate.org/ogm/).

Answer (score 1):

When we're using MongoDB as the database for a Spring Boot application, we can't use @GeneratedValue annotation in our models as it's not available. Hence we need a method to produce the same effect as we'll have if we're using JPA and an SQL database.

Use this for more reference - [click](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field)